Finding a sequence for two different series so that both converge
I have to solve the following problem:
Find a sequence $(a_n)_{n\in \mathbb{N}}$​, with $a_n \neq 0$ , such that the series
$\sum\limits_{k=1}^{\infty} a_n$ and $\sum\limits_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n^2a_n}$
both converge, and prove their convergence.
So far I just tried out a number of sequences like $\frac{1}{n^2}$ and $\frac{1}{n(n+1)}$ but got nowwhere so now I am starting to wonder if there even exists a sequence so that the two series both converge. How would I go about proving that?

$\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac1k$ diverges but $\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^k}k$ converges. You'll have an easier time making the series converge if you alternate between positive and negative terms, as they somewhat cancel each other out.

Take $a_n=(-1)^{n}n^{-1/2}$ the first series converges by Alternating Series Test and the second one converges absolutely.
